# caching an xml file in clojure and compojure

Tags: xml, multithreading, caching, clojure, compojure

I have a webserver running `compojure`. The webserver reads data from an XML file provided by another server. I don't want to bomb the provider of the file with requests and the XML file doesn't change too often, so I figured I need some kind of caching.

I could either store the XML file locally and refresh it every *X* minutes. The other way would be to reparse the original in the same time interval and store the file in memory? Maybe I can use `refs` or `atoms` for this? This process should probably run in a different thread. How would I configure this?

In the future I might have quite a big pool of these XML files that will all need updating.

Which would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could start with `core.memoize` library:

https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize

Later on you can always move to something more sophisticated and separated from a JVM's memory - such as Redis or memcached.